# copying to generalPasteboard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uipasteboard

I am not receiving a clear answer on both Google and here about this; I don't know why it has to be so difficult. What is the code that let's you copy to generalPasteboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on stackoverflow i found this [about pasteboard in objective c](http://mobileorchard.com/new-in-iphone-30-tutorial-series-part-3-copy-paste-with-uipasteboard/)

Comment: Well... I didn't see that. Thank you. :)